# How to link a Myspace band page with a Facebook band page?

Tags: facebook, myspace

When I log in to our Myspace band page and use the "linked networks" function to link the Myspace profile to a Facebook profile it always uses my personal Facebook profile. What I want to achieve is that updates posted to the Myspace page (which is the band's primary online presence) are automatically posted to the Facebook band page as well.

How can I specify a Facebook **page** as the target for the link?

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. [RSS Graffitti](http://apps.facebook.com/rssgraffiti) appears to be good enough for what I wanted to do.